# Add Check Constraint not working SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, check-constraints

I need to add a constraint to a table such that column ab is always greater than column h. I have tried

```
ALTER TABLE batting
ADD constraint possibleHits check (ab>h);
```

But that returns

```
ERROR:  check constraint "possiblehits" is violated by some row

********** Error **********

ERROR: check constraint "possiblehits" is violated by some row
SQL state: 23514
```

as an error.

I have run

```
select * from batting where ab<h
```

and it returns no rows.

Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong? or is there a way to do something like add

```
NOT VALID
```

to the statement so that it will not enforce the constraint on existing rows?
I know that that works in mysql but in postgres it only works on keys.

EDIT:

So as was pointed out there are instances where ab = h however is there a way to exclude existing rows from the constraint?

Comment: there may be some existing rows where ab=h ??

Comment: @BWS there are about 6000 rows where ab=h (hits head on desk for not seeing the obvious)

Comment: You can add an `is_old` column to the table and then check `ab>h or is_old`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check for values where ab=h. I'm sure you'll find your problem.

See below for one example of it working.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a275c)</kbd>

Comment: there are about 6000 rows where ab=h (hits head on desk for not seeing the obvious).

Comment: Happens to the best :p.

Comment: @thermite. I didn't realize you edited your question. What do you mena exclude the rows from the constraint? The constraint will be in place for all the rows. Your two options are change your constraint to ab>=h or remove/update the rows that are violating the original cosntraint

Comment: So  changing the constraint to  ab>=h works for that specific query(actually it is more correct for the problem) but is there a way to add constraints to a table and leave violating data in the table. ie add constraints only to changes you will make to the table.

Comment: No. If you think about it, that wouldn't make sense. Having a constraint like that ensures that there are no rows here ab < h. If some could be left out of the validation, that statement wouldn't be true.

Answer (score 3):

If you want column ab is always greater than column h, then you need to delete those 6000 rows where ab=h, if don't want to delete those 6000 rows, you can try this.

```
 ALTER TABLE batting
 ADD constraint possibleHits check(ab>=h);
```